# TypeError: method() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given if i did register api

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

cant do work my register_api if i have view

```
class RegistrationUsersApi(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    def get(self, request):
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        serializer = UserSerializerView(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request):
        serializer_class = SerializerUserRegistration(data=request.data)
        data={}
        if serializer_class.is_valid():
            new_user = serializer_class.save()
            data['response'] = 'Ура ты создал нового персонажа, героя, человека, или не создал?'
            data['email'] = new_user.email
            data['username'] = new_user.username
        else:
            serializer_class.errors
        return Response(data)
```

and i have my serilizer

```
class SerializerUserRegistration(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    password2 = serializers.CharField(style={'input_type': 'password'}, write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password', 'password2']
        extra_kwargs = {
            'password': {'write_only': True}
        }

    def save(self):
        user = User(
            email=self.validated_data['email'],
            username=self.validated_data['username'],
        )
        password = self.validated_data['password']
        password2 = self.validated_data['password2']

        if password != password2:
            raise serializers.ValidationError({'password': 'Password must match'})
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user
```

and my usermodel

```
class User(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="profile")
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    is_organizer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    info_car = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    second_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.MainIndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('registration/', views.RegistrationUsersApi, name='registration')
]
```

and my root urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('mainapp.urls')),
    path('api/token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    path('api/token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
    path("api/accounts/", include("mainapp.urls")),
]
```

why my register doesnt work. i was try to post with postman
why does Python tell me I gave it two arguments, when I only gave one? and why i have that problem i dont know

Comment: For which line are you getting the error?

Comment: when I wrote the question, I noticed that I have the wrong view, did not add as_view () on urls. path. But it doesn't help to the end, the following error I get
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Field name `username` is not valid for model `User`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when I wrote the question, I noticed that I have the wrong view, did not add `as_view ()` on urls. path
and

My user model was with the same name as the standard one, which caused problems, I deleted my model and started using the standard one and everything began to work for me